Django SSO integration for JumpCloud
Newbie question. I am trying to configure my company admin website to use JumpCloud for SSO auth. I can't find any simple solution. Is there a conventional/standard practice way to integrate OIDC into a simple Django website? Secondly, if my web application runs in a private network (ie No public access), does the IDP have to have access to my web application to return the auth code (back channel)?
